# Launch iTunes and iPhoto when external USB drive is connected

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, external-disk, filesystem

Is there a code that I can just copy an paste into Terminal or Automator? If not what is the best Application to download?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very easily using [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com), a free (open-source) application:

> ControlPlane, a fork of MarcoPolo, brings context and location sensitive awareness to OS X. With ControlPlane you can intelligently reconfigure your Mac or perform any number of actions based on input from a wide variety of evidence sources [...]

*from: https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane*

It's very easy to set-up. You define a "context", select a rule (or multiple rules):

[image: ControlPlane rules]

And link an action to it:

[image]